# Oracle listener up but instance connection blocked ORA-12528 / ORA-12505!

Tags: oracle, instance, listener

Its been one week since i last try to run my final project that i worked in my last internship at some banking company.

Suddenly, my webapps (java project) in eclipse cant start. In the log it says that it failed to make a connection to the oracle database, with some error listener in it. So I try to connect the database manually from the sql developer. It says ORA-12528: TNS:Listener: All Appropriate instances are blocking new connections .

I've read some solutions, and i try to restart the oracle services including the orcl and listener. after I restarted it, the error becomes ORA-12505: TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor. after a while, it becomes ORA-12528 again. can someone help? please. my thesis defense is next week.

alert_ORCL.txt log (SID=ORCL):

```
***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12641, connecting to:
 (LOCAL=NO)

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 05-MAR-2015 21:28:24
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12641

TNS-12641: Authentication service failed to initialize
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (4204) as a result of ORA-609
Thu Mar 05 21:28:26 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12641, connecting to:
 (LOCAL=NO)

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Windows NT TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 05-MAR-2015 21:28:26
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12641

TNS-12641: Authentication service failed to initialize
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
opiodr aborting process unknown ospid (7280) as a result of ORA-609
Thu Mar 05 21:28:28 2015
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified
O/S-Error: (OS 1) Incorrect function. !
Thu Mar 05 21:28:40 2015
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified
O/S-Error: (OS 1) Incorrect function. !
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: Message 4500 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=SOSD
O/S-Error: (OS 1) Incorrect function. !
Thu Mar 05 21:28:49 2015
Errors in file c:\app\nico\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace\orcl_psp0_3752.trc:
ORA-09314: sltln: error translating logical name
OSD-04503: Message 4503 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=SOSD
PSP0 (ospid: 3752): terminating the instance due to error 9314
Fri Mar 06 09:33:19 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Fri Mar 06 09:33:21 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=2532 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:21 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=3568 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=3572 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=3212 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=3856 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=3332 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=3828 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=3648 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=3840 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=2176 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=3688 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=2612 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=3004 
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=1180 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
alter database mount exclusive
Fri Mar 06 09:33:22 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=2088 
                                                                                                                                                     Fri Mar 06 09:39:14 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Fri Mar 06 09:39:39 2015
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Fri Mar 06 09:40:08 2015
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Fri Mar 06 09:40:17 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=6128 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:18 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=6132 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=6136 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=6140 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=4212 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=3460 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=2884 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=4644 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=2744 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=5160 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=5156 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=5228 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=5252 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=5240 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Fri Mar 06 09:40:19 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=5244 
Fri Mar 06 09:40:34 2015
alter database mount exclusive
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Fri Mar 06 09:40:40 2015
Checker run found 1 new persistent data failures
Fri Mar 06 11:19:13 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12638, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 06-MAR-2015 11:19:13
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12638

TNS-12638: Credential retrieval failed
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
Fri Mar 06 12:17:21 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Fri Mar 06 12:17:26 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=3276 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:26 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=368 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=4952 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=900 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=888 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=868 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=884 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=880 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=876 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=832 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=776 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=4956 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=5008 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=4860 
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=2032 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Fri Mar 06 12:17:27 2015
alter database mount exclusive
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Fri Mar 06 14:09:50 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12638, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 06-MAR-2015 14:09:50
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12638

TNS-12638: Credential retrieval failed
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
Mon Mar 09 14:25:48 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Mon Mar 09 14:25:53 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=3612 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:53 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=3616 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=3620 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=3628 
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=3632 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=3636 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=3644 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=3648 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=3652 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:54 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=3656 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:55 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=3660 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:55 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=3664 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:55 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=3668 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:55 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=3672 
Mon Mar 09 14:25:55 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=3676 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Mon Mar 09 14:25:56 2015
alter database mount exclusive
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Mon Mar 09 16:00:16 2015
Shutting down instance (immediate)
Shutting down instance: further logons disabled
Stopping background process MMNL
Stopping background process MMON
License high water mark = 1
All dispatchers and shared servers shutdown
alter database close normal
ORA-1507 signalled during: alter database close normal...
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=6964 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=8328 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=2460 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=7756 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=2280 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=7040 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=8340 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=7728 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=796 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=5292 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=7896 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=4812 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=6792 
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=8808 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
alter database mount exclusive
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Mon Mar 09 16:00:28 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=6436 
Mon Mar 09 16:12:11 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
Mon Mar 09 16:12:26 2015
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
Mon Mar 09 16:12:37 2015
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Mon Mar 09 16:13:04 2015
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Mon Mar 09 16:13:09 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=5916 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=5920 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=5924 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=6004 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=6008 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=6016 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=6028 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=6032 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=6052 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=6056 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=6060 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=6064 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=6068 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=6072 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Mon Mar 09 16:13:10 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=6076 
Mon Mar 09 16:13:18 2015
alter database mount exclusive
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Mon Mar 09 16:23:23 2015
Shutting down instance (immediate)
Shutting down instance: further logons disabled
Stopping background process MMNL
Stopping background process MMON
License high water mark = 1
All dispatchers and shared servers shutdown
alter database close normal
ORA-1507 signalled during: alter database close normal...
Mon Mar 09 16:24:43 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
System parameters with non-default values:
  processes                = 150
  memory_target            = 1232M
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\ORADATA\ORCL\CONTROL01.CTL"
  control_files            = "C:\APP\NICO\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\ORCL\CONTROL02.CTL"
  db_block_size            = 8192
  compatible               = "11.2.0.0.0"
  db_recovery_file_dest    = "C:\app\Nico\flash_recovery_area"
  db_recovery_file_dest_size= 3852M
  undo_tablespace          = "UNDOTBS1"
  remote_login_passwordfile= "EXCLUSIVE"
  db_domain                = ""
  dispatchers              = "(PROTOCOL=TCP) (SERVICE=orclXDB)"
  local_listener           = "LISTENER_ORCL"
  audit_file_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO\ADMIN\ORCL\ADUMP"
  audit_trail              = "DB"
  db_name                  = "orcl"
  open_cursors             = 300
  diagnostic_dest          = "C:\APP\NICO"
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
PMON started with pid=2, OS id=6308 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
VKTM started with pid=3, OS id=8020 at elevated priority
VKTM running at (10)millisec precision with DBRM quantum (100)ms
OER 7451 in Load Indicator : Error Code = OSD-04500: illegal option specified !
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
GEN0 started with pid=4, OS id=7444 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
DIAG started with pid=5, OS id=5936 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
DBRM started with pid=6, OS id=8088 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
PSP0 started with pid=7, OS id=5216 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
DIA0 started with pid=8, OS id=5280 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
MMAN started with pid=9, OS id=8160 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
DBW0 started with pid=10, OS id=5940 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
LGWR started with pid=11, OS id=6020 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
CKPT started with pid=12, OS id=4260 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
SMON started with pid=13, OS id=7496 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
RECO started with pid=14, OS id=1500 
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
MMON started with pid=15, OS id=6960 
starting up 1 dispatcher(s) for network address '(ADDRESS=(PARTIAL=YES)(PROTOCOL=TCP))'...
starting up 1 shared server(s) ...
ORACLE_BASE from environment = C:\app\Nico
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
alter database mount exclusive
Mon Mar 09 16:24:44 2015
MMNL started with pid=16, OS id=6624 
ORA-214 signalled during: alter database mount exclusive...
Mon Mar 09 16:33:24 2015


***********************************************************************

Fatal NI connect error 12638, connecting to:
 (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=beq)))

  VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for 32-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
  Time: 09-MAR-2015 16:33:24
  Tracing not turned on.
  Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12638

TNS-12638: Credential retrieval failed
    ns secondary err code: 0
    nt main err code: 0
    nt secondary err code: 0
    nt OS err code: 0
Mon Mar 09 16:39:39 2015
Starting ORACLE instance (normal)
LICENSE_MAX_SESSION = 0
LICENSE_SESSIONS_WARNING = 0
Picked latch-free SCN scheme 2
Using LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1 parameter default value as USE_DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST
Autotune of undo retention is turned on. 
IMODE=BR
ILAT =27
LICENSE_MAX_USERS = 0
SYS auditing is disabled
Starting up:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options.
Using parameter settings in server-side spfile C:\APP\NICO\PRODUCT\11.2.0\DBHOME_1\DATABASE\SPFILEORCL.ORA
```